# Rails: How to display categories and subcategories in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display `categories` and `subcategories` in ruby on rails

**I am getting this error**

[image]

This is my `categories` table, from which I want to display categories and subcategories.

[image]

My code in `category.rb`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Category'
end
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end
    def new
        @category = Category.new
    end
    def edit
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        @category = Category.new(params[:category].permit!)
        if @category.save
            redirect_to categories_url
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
    def update
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
        if @category.update_attributes(params[:category].permit!)
            redirect_to categories_url
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end
    def destroy
        Category.destroy(params[:id])
        redirect_to categories_url
    end
end
```

view/categories/index.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @category do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, @category.category_id), :include_blank => true %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>`
```

error is

[image]

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :organisations, :controllers => {:registrations => "organisations/registrations"}
  devise_for :coaches, :controllers => {:registrations => "coaches/registrations"}
  devise_for :students, :controllers => {:registrations => "students/registrations"}
  devise_for :admins
  root to: "home#index"
  devise_for :users, path: 'users', path_names: {sign_in: 'sign-in', sign_out: 'sign-out', confirmation: 'verification'}
  namespace :coaches do
    resources :study_materials
  end
  namespace :coaches do
    resources :programmes
  end
  namespace :admin do
    resources :coaches
  end
  get 'programmes', to: 'programmes#index', as: 'programmes'
  get 'programmes/*hierarchy/:program_slug', to: 'programmes#show', as: 'programme'
  get 'programmes/*hierarchy', to: 'programmes#category', as: 'categories'
  get 'start-coaching', to: 'home#start_coaching'
 resources :categories
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your nil class you have to add this in your `def index` method

```
def index
  @categories = Category.where("parent_id IS NULL")
  @category = Category.new
end

def get_subscategories
  @subscategories = Category.where(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  render :partial => "subscategories", :object => @subscategories
end
```

**index.html**

```
<%= select_tag "parent_category", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select a parent category", :onchange => "update_subscategories_div(this.value)" %>
<div id="versionsDiv">
</div>
```

**_subscategories.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@subscategories, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select a parent category" %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match "/get_subscategories" => "categories#get_subscategories"
```

**application.js**

```
function update_subscategories_div(parent_id) {  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_subscategories",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"parent_id" : parent_id},
    dataType: "html"
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#versionsDiv").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

This is reference articles for you [how-categories-sub-categories-in-tree-hierarchy-inside-a-dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442105/show-categories-sub-categories-in-tree-hierarchy-inside-a-dropdown)

Comment: THanks @Muhammad Akbar Bin Wida .. it worked.. thanks thanks thanks alot :)

Comment: i want two select options on clicking the each parent in first select option, i want its accordance children in next select box. any easy way through this

Comment: @sreena I just share to how to get started. You need ajax to get subs-categories by selecting a parent. This is a good toturial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945529/rails-select-tag-with-ajax-action-rails-3-and-jquery. If you have any question to do this tutorial. Feel free to ask me question.

Comment: Thanks @ Muhamad Akbar Bin Widayat :),  let me try first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90305/discussion-between-sreena-and-muhamad-akbar-bin-widayat).

Answer (score 0):

As you the `form` in `index.html.erb`, the `index` method should contain `@category = Category.new`

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
  @category = Category.new
end
```

Comment: thanks pavan ,this problem is solved, but arised new error in routes. iwill add above the problem and my routes file

Comment: @sreena Please update your question with the error and the routes. Please don't edit my answer to post them.

Comment: change your routes.rb in line `get 'programmes/*hierarchy', to: 'categories#index', as: 'categories'`. Then restart your server.