# Rails Optimize tree structure code by eager-loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tree, treeview, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to show a drop down with tree structure.By using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442105/show-categories-sub-categories-in-tree-hierarchy-inside-a-dropdown) SO solution given by @manoj, the code for category_options_array displays the tree wonderfully in the select form control for a model with fewer entries but another model which has has about 30 parent ids and some of them with 1-level depth, the server crashes. In fact even when it uses for say 20 parent_ids, it executes 20 SQL queries which just for one drop-down control is too much.

I tried collecting it into a cache - like this

```
@categories = Category.where('parent_id = ? AND id != ?', parent_id, current_id ).order(:name)
@categories.each do |c| .....
```

however, it runs same 20 SQL queries and 20 cache.

When I read eager loading it's generally for a join condition and I could not find any example for a single model.Can it be optimised by eager loading/any-other-way to have query run once and arrange array to display?TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer in code without seeing how your model's data structure is set up, but generally speaking you can use an "includes" statement to eager load, which also support nesting:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

How do the queries look when you include the sub-model?

Comment: It runs as many select queries as there are category records and even after collecting them in a hash @categories it runs all those...strange!! Category model is:  name:string, parent_id:integer (default value = 0)

Comment: can you post a gist with your model definitions?